# To what extent should I investigate a Low Quality Posts review?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, low-quality-posts

I just failed [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/27710714) on a copy paste of another legit answer with a spam link appended.

Granted, the link isn't even well-disguised, but it isn't blatantly obvious when you're judging whether the answer contains something reminiscent of an answer, i.e.

1. Not link only
2. Not spam only
3. Contains something considerable as a solution

If I were to click through to the post, it would have been pretty obvious. That said, the review UI, combined with the [guidelines](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155538/what-are-the-guidelines-for-reviewing/180029#180029), gave me the impression that I shouldn't spend that much time on a single review. In particular

> Most of the time, the reviewer shouldn't need domain expertise to perform the review.

Should I have investigated more?

Comment: Checking external links is basic due diligence, IMO.

Comment: @yivi Noted. Will do that.

Comment: *"Most of the time, the reviewer shouldn't need domain expertise to perform the review."* - That does mention how much time you should spend on reviews at all, how is it related to *"under the impression I shouldn't spend that much time"*?

Comment: @Nick You don't need to judge the content, just that they're content at all.

Comment: You do need to judge the content, just not its correctness, etc. the point in that guideline is that, if you come across a review that is about python and you know _nothing_ about python. You should still be able to determine if it's low quality. It's not an invitation to review quickly, you should be taking your time.

Comment: As Nick pointed out, you should spend enough time on any review to do it properly. Trying to do it fast is not a good idea at all. It leads to avoidable mistakes. The consequences doing it fast with audits is minor. Doing it with real reviews is a bigger problem.

Comment: @yivi I would say, except for linik-only answers - which only require one to check if the question isn't asking for links and if it isn't - one can skip further diligence / checks and just pick respective delete option

Comment: @gnat Even for link only answers it's worth doing I think. Flagging as spam is quite different than flagging as NAA.

Comment: @yivi agreed. In cases when I see high possibility of it being a spam (eg noticing user name as part of URL) I tend to dig deeper, trying to get to more appropriate option. Although I can understand reviewers who prefer to cut corners and proceed with a less effort consuming delete option (as long as they don't pick Edit or Looks OK I can't blame them)

Answer (score 15):

One giant red flag you missed here was the oddity of the link.

1. It's linking keywords wholly unrelated to the post. What does "Internet marketing service" have to do with a question about ReactJS? That alone should make you wonder why the link is there
2. It's linking the root domain, not a specific article. I expect an actual reference link to point to a specific page.

In this case, the user was actively making copy-pasta spam on another question as well, which is why this post drew 6 spam flags. As always, when you have any suspicions, click through to the post itself. Audits trip you up only when you're lulled into a false sense of security.

Answer (score 10):

You seem to have noticed that the answer

> *...is a copy paste of another legit answer*

So, with or without the spam link, and with or without domain expertise, how did you come to the assessment that it "Looks OK"?

The answer was presented in the Low Quality Posts review queue (which implies that *somebody* had already flagged it as dodgy). If there is nothing 'obviously' wrong with it, then you should at least *suspect* something more subtle; clicking the "link" link (before any other action) allows you to check for a copy/paste of another answer. The review would have told you that there *were* other answers. So:

> *Should I have investigated more?*

Yes!

Clicking that link would have taken you to the *actual* post, where, in this case, you would have immediately spotted that it was an audit. Were it *not* an audit, that link would have enabled you to spot that it was a copy-paste of another answer, and flag accordingly (were it not spam).

Comment: I failed, and clicked through. The review UI doesn't show other posts. BTW, if the queue should catch copy pastes, the UI is doing a horrible job at facilitating that.

Comment: _"you should at least suspect something more subtle"_, what? You are suggesting to meta-review the queue, because the necessary information to judge an answer isn't immediately present. That's broken UI in my book. If I should click through every answer, then _the entire page should be shown in the UI_.

Comment: The UI is not broken: it has the "link" there for your convenience.